# Getting current row in PreviewMouseDown event of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've got a problem with getting a row in `PreviewMouseDown` event of a `DataGrid`. The `DataGrid.SelectedItem` property in this event is still `null`. In stead of it I've found a `MouseOverRow` property, but it is not accessible. Actually I looked everywhere and can't find any information about these two properties - `MouseOverCell` and `MouseOverRow`.

[image]

Can someone tell me how to get the current row in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get item behind the ckicked row from the `e.OriginalSource` context.

```
var myItem = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext as MyItemClass
```

Comment: So easy! I was trying to go through the visual tree - it worked, but your way is much more  elegant. Thanks!

Comment: `DataContext` is inherited down the visual tree. As long as `OriginalSource` is within `DataGridRow` container it will share its `DataContext`